# Clang-15 vs Clang-14 local static init guards

Tags: static, clang, atomic, clang++, cortex-m

I'm using Clang++ to compile for a Cortex-M0+ target, and in moving from version 14 to version 15 I've found a difference in the code generated for guard variables for local statics.

So, for example:

```
int main()
{
    static knl::QueueN<uint32_t, 8> valQueue;
    ...
}
```

Clang-14 generates the following:

```
ldr r0, .LCPI0_4
ldrb    r0, [r0]
dmb sy
lsls    r0, r0, #31
beq .LBB0_8
```

Clang-15 now generates:

```
ldr r0, .LCPI0_4
movs    r1, #2
bl  __atomic_load_1
lsls    r0, r0, #31
beq .LBB0_8
```

Why the change?  Was the Clang 14 code incorrect?

EDITED TO ADD:

Note that an important consequence of this is that the second case actually requires an implementation of __atomic_load_1 to be provided from somewhere external to the compiler (e.g. -latomic), whereas the first doesn't.

EDITED TO ADD:

See https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/58184 for the LLVM devs' response to this.

Comment: You normally only get guards with non-constant static initializers.  `static int x = 1;` can just go in `.data`, with the scope difference between file vs. function only being dealt with at compile time.  I assume your actual [mcve] was something like `int foo(int arg) { static int x = arg;` so the initializer depends on a runtime variable.

Comment: You're right, I cheated on the source code.  Updated with the real example.  The generated code is, however, verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

Neither one is wrong.  It's just that in the first version, the code to do the atomic load is inlined, and in the second version it's called as a library function instead.  If you look at the code within `__atomic_load_1` you will probably find it executes the exact same instructions, or equivalent ones.

Each way has pros and cons.  The inline version avoids the overhead of a function call, while the library version makes it possible to select code at runtime that is best optimized for the features of the actual runtime CPU.

The difference could be a conscious design change between clang versions, or a difference in the code gen and optimization options you used, or different configuration options when your clang installation was built.  Someone else might know more details about what controls this.  But it isn't anything to worry about as far as proper behavior of your code.

Comment: I guess it's more an academic question - although one important practical difference is that the second case actually requires an implementation of __atomic_load_1 to be provided from somewhere (e.g. -latomic), whereas the first doesn't.

Comment: Regarding build options and clang configuration, the two cases use an identical clang++ command line - the only difference is the version of clang itself (running on Windows, installed from the official Win64 build of LLVM).